# simplify if isset case php

Tags: php

sorry if this quite a easy question, but i cant find any thread the same as this.

lets say we are setting the values like

```
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="only_admin" value="1" /> Only Admin</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="can_request" value="1" /> Can Request</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="can_offer" value="1" /> Can Offer</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="can_post" value="1" /> Can Post</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="is_maintenance" value="1" /> Is Maintenance</li>
```

then on our server side we put this

```
        if (isset($_POST['only_admin'])) {
            $permission['only_admin'] = $_POST['only_admin'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['can_request'])) {
            $permission['can_request'] = $_POST['can_request'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['can_offer'])) {
            $permission['can_offer'] = $_POST['can_offer'];
        }   

        if (isset($_POST['can_post'])) {
            $permission['can_post'] = $_POST['can_post'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['is_maintenance'])) {
            $permission['is_maintenance'] = $_POST['is_maintenance'];
        }
```

is there a simpler version to above code ?

thanks!
Adam Ramadhan

*ps* please tag me if there is already a good thread about this.*

Comment: For readablility reasons you could do `$permission['only_admin'] = !empty($_POST['only_admin']) ? 1 : 0;` This is much more readable but won't really simplify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$values = array("only_admin", 
                "can_request", 
                "can_offer", 
                "can_post", 
                "is_maintenance");

foreach($values as $v)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$v]))
    {
        $permission[$v] = $_POST[$v];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are some ways to simplify it, look at this... It's not the only solution, but it's a clean one:

```
$permissions = array(
    'only_admin' => 0, 
    'can_offer' => 0,
    'can_request' => 0,
    'can_post' => 0,
    'is_maintenance' => 0,
);
foreach(array_keys($permissions) as $permission){
    if(isset($_POST[$permission])){
        $permissions[$permissions] = $_POST[$permission];
    }
}
```

This becomes highly powerful the more permissions you have!

Comment: best, i think i go with this!, how could i never thought this.

Comment: Then why have you marked Flukey's as the right answer might i ask?

Comment: for the viewers, its more universal. without the default value. btw `$permissions[$permission] = $_POST[$permission];` thanks again mathieu

Answer (score 2):

Needs a bit more work, but why don't you just use:

```
$permission = $_POST;
```

You could also add in_array checks so that `$permission` gets only specific keys in case there are more values sent by the form.

Comment: Dangerous way, because you will copy all data in $_POST which doesn't mean it is all data you need. That method could use an array_intersect to take only $_POST values.

Comment: I know, that's why I said it needs more work and suggested using in_array to make a whitelist of keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily write a function for this since $_POST is also a global variable. For instance:

```
<?php
function check_permissions() {
$permissions_array = array("only_admin", "can_request", "can_offer", "can_post", "is_maintenance");
foreach ($_POST as $p => $value)
{
  if (in_array($p, $permissions_array))
  { 
     $permission[$p] = $value;
  }
return $permission;
?>
```

}
    ?>

Answer (score 1):

Please, try:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="permission[only_admin]" value="1" /> Only Admin</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="permission[can_request]" value="1" /> Can Request</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="permission[can_offer]" value="1" /> Can Offer</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="permission[can_post]" value="1" /> Can Post</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="permission[is_maintenance]" value="1" /> Is Maintenance</li>

$permission[] = $_POST['permission'];
```

and then filter unset values from `$permission[]` if you want

Answer (score -1):

```
$permission['only_admin'] = isset($_POST['only_admin']);
```

And so on for the rest.

Comment: This is invalid, because it will set TRUE or FALSE to $permission array and maybe it wasn't boolean flags that were copied, at least the current code doesn't see it as a boolean

Comment: Checkboxes are boolean by nature. They either have a value or they don't.  If you generated the checkbox you should know what the value it should have is.  However, a malicious form submission might put anything in the value field (code to attempt an SQL injection or anything else) and the above method will block such attempts dead in their tracks.

Comment: Checkboxes' state is boolean by nature, NOT the value, the value can be anything you want from JSON to XML data passing by strings and numbers. So if the value of the checkbox was an ID of a permission in a database, your isset($_POST['only_admin']) fails because it will return true or false and not the original value="number" in the tag